# A partial proof that a set is connected

Tags: general-topology, intersection-theory

I am trying to prove that the following set is connected.

$
R(a,b) = \{ W \in [0,1]^{m \times m} \, | \, \, \sum_{ij=1}^m W_{ij}=a,tr(W^3)=b,\,W_{ij}=W_{ji}\} 
$

where 
$m \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \geq 2$ and $ a,b \in [0,1]$ and $tr(\cdot)$ is the matrix trace.

My partial result is:

The imagen of the set $ R(b) = \{ W \in [0,1]^{m \times m} \, | \, \, tr(W^3)=b,\,W_{ij}=W_{ji}\}  $ by the transformation $f:[0,1]^{m \times m} \rightarrow [0,1]^{m \times m}$, $f(W) = W^3$ is convex.

Since if $A,B \in f(R(b))$ then $tr(\alpha A +(1-\alpha)B) = \alpha tr(A) +(1-\alpha)tr(B) =b$.

Moreover, the application $f(W)$ is a homeomorphism when $W$ is nonsigular. The set of nonsigular matrices is dense and has two connected components. Hence the preimagen of $f$ i.e. $R(b)$ is connected.

Therefore $R(a,b)$ is the intersection of a hyperplane $R(a) = \{ W \in [0,1]^{m \times m} \, | \, \, \sum_{ij=1}^m W_{ij}=a,W_{ij}=W_{ji}\} 
$ and $R(b)$. However I have no clue on how to prove or disprove if $R(a,b)$ is connected.

Some of you has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to find a linear factor for  the polynomial $p(W) = tr(W^3)-a$, but it was not possible?. hence my question,. I think that set is connected.

Comment: I do as well, but I have no idea on how to prove it.